# Is the sentence "I went to the balcony." grammatical and idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> I was in my room, then I went to the balcony.

Does it need any preposition like "onto", "out to", "out onto", "out on" or "on" instead of "to"?

Answer (score 1):

It works as you currently have it. But most of the prepositions you suggested would also work, with "out on" being the most commonly used in my experience.

Comment: I think most speakers would use a preposition.

Comment: Yeah you're right, which makes it grammatical but not idiomatic I suppose.